# Accidentally set 'sleep-inactive-ac-timeout' too low

Tags: suspend, power-management, dconf, gsettings

My desktop is on AC power and is set to suspend after a certain amount of time.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
'suspend'
```

Then I ran this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 5
```

and now it is going into power suspend every 5 seconds (instead of 5 minutes).
I should have run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 300
```

but it's too late now.

Any way to get myself out of this situation?

Comment: You could try entering the root shell by booting into Recovery Mode from Grub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Brute solution

... But what wil work anyway is to start up with a live usb, navigate to `/home/yourname/.config` in your installed ubuntu (inside `File System` in the left pane of nautilus) and delete or rename the folder `dconf`.

On next startup, a new dconf database will be created, with default settings. You'll lose quite a few customized settings (if you set them), all the ones in gsettings/dconf, but it works.